# git-crypt update file thats been encrypted

Tags: git, npm, git-crypt

Ive a `.env` file, and a number of others encrypted with git-crypt.

`git-crypt` lock asks to clean working directory. Appending `--force` removes all changes to .env and just gives me the original file

I'm adding new values into the `.env` file and want to re-encrypt the file anew, then check it in to git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer I found was running `git-crypt lock --force; git-crypt unlock;`, pasting in the .env changes, then in the git cli running a commit. It converts to binary in a webhook that looked to not work correctly when interfacing with a git ui like `gitkraken`